# IB Convergence Theory Questionn

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK1zQ.png)

Hello, I just started learning about convergence so I am still new to the concept. I have a problem answering question part ai and aii. I do not understand how to answer this question. Can someone help me understand? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- If $0 < u_n \le 1$ then $u_n^2 \le u_n$.
- If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges, then $u_n \le 1$ for all large $n$.
- Use the above two facts to show that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty u_n^2 \le \sum_{n=N}^\infty u_n$ for some large number $N$.
- For (ii), try to come up with a counterexample involving the divergence of the harmonic series $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots$.